# Can I call the following code "Tail Recursive"? -Haskell function

Tags: haskell, recursion, optimization, tail-recursion, tail

*I am supposed to implement tail recursive functions only. Is this code tail recursive, considering that at each call I have three functions working inside it for the answer?*

```
anyfunction :: (Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> a
anyfunction n [] ys ws = anyfunction n ws ys ws
anyfunction (-1) (x:xs) ys ws = something x xs
anyfunction n (x:xs) ys ws = anyfunction (n+1) (someotherthing(something x xs) (x:xs) []) (ys ++ [(something x xs)]) ws
```

**Please, consider that: 'something' and 'someotherthing' are all tail recursive functions. I am sure of that.**

Comment: If you are sure that `anyfunction` is tail recursive, then what is your question?

Comment: So you're sure that `anyfunction` is tail recursive, and your question is whether `anyfunction` is tail recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anyfunction`, as defined, is tail-recursive, no matter what `someotherthing` and `something` are.

The only thing that depends on whether `someotherthing` and `something` are tail-recursive is how much `anyfunction` will benefit from tail-call optimization.